# Check if object exists in database without loading object with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a way in NHibernate to check if an object exists in the database without having to get/load the object?

Comment: I don't understand. If there is no object in the DB, how are getting or loading an object. The object should come back as null. Or your result list will be empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could always do a count.

I tend to use DetachedCriteria, so I'd have something like:

```
var criteria = // some criteria that will identify your object

var result = criteria
    .GetExecutableCriteria(Session)
    .SetProjection(Projections.RowCountInt64())
    .UniqueResult();

return result > 0;
```

Answer (score 32):

You could use one of the following 3 queries (or you could use Criteria API Projections.RowCountInt64() from David answer):

```
bool exist = session.Query<Employee>()
    .Any(x => x.EmployeeID == 1);

bool exist = session.QueryOver<Employee>()
    .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == 1)
    .RowCount() > 0;

bool exist = session.Query<Employee>()
    .Count(x => x.EmployeeID == 1) > 0;
```

Just keep in mind that Any is worst of those three because it fetches entity. Here is sql query generated for each:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select TOP (1)  employee0_.EmployeeID as EmployeeID0_, employee0_.Name as Name0_ from Employee employee0_ where employee0_.EmployeeID=@p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM Employee this_ WHERE this_.EmployeeID = @p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1

exec sp_executesql N'select cast(count(*) as INT) as col_0_0_ from Employee employee0_ where employee0_.EmployeeID=@p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1
```

Comment: OTOH, Any may be the best from a performance perspective -- "count" can be a heavy duty function to call, depending on data volumes, indexes, and the like. A TOP (1) will just seek the appropriate index. Is there an equivalent of `SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM table WHERE ...` which would be the best again (as it wouldn't actually pull any data from the table).

Comment: See my answer for a query that does not fetch the entity or use count. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24083783/12752

Answer (score 12):

So I let myself to do some tests with your examples `@Jamie Ide @Darius Kucinskas @Dmitry`

[image]

So:

```
var exists = session
.CreateQuery("select 1 from Widget where _color = 'green'")
.SetMaxResults(1)
.UniqueResult<Int32?>()
.HasValue;
```

in my case was **18%** faster than

```
bool exist = session.Query<Employee>()
    .Any(x => x.EmployeeID == 1);
```

**14%** than

```
bool exist = session.Query<Employee>()
    .Count(x => x.EmployeeID == 1) > 0;
```

and **8%**

```
bool exist = session.QueryOver<Employee>()
    .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == 1)
    .RowCount() > 0;
```

So in my opinion even if hard coded query is fastest the

```
bool exist = session.QueryOver<Employee>()
    .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == 1)
    .RowCount() > 0;
```

is best option because of **good habits and code clearness**

Comment: Until you get many millions of entries in "Employee", assuming the condition does not compare the primary key and no index exists.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on Darius Kucinskas' excellent answer, you can avoid fetching the entity using Select:

```
bool exist = session.Query<Employee>()
                    .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == 1)
                    .Select(x => x.EmployeeID)
                    .Any();
```

As mentioned, the query performance should be the same however I would expect this to reduce network traffic.

Comment: I use this technique also, but I am sad that I have use so many lines to resolve problem "NHibernate loads to many data instead of using EXISTS".

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this...

```
var fooExists = session.Query<Foo>().Any(f => /*condition*/);
```

Comment: This should be var fooExists = session.Query<Foo>().Any(f => /*condition*/) Where is redundant. This is bad idea because Any will return all columns (full entity).

Comment: @DariusKucinskas that is not correct. Both constructs result in the EXACT SAME SQL. Using `Any(x)` instead of `Where(x).Any()` is just a bit cleaner.

Comment: Any is bad because it fetches entity form database, row count is better in this situation.

Comment: please, read my answer below, here is what SQLquery is generated by NH Linq provider for Any: exec sp_executesql N'select TOP (1)  employee0_.EmployeeID as EmployeeID0_, employee0_.Name as Name0_ from Employee employee0_ where employee0_.EmployeeID=@p0',N'@p0 int',@p0=1

Comment: My bad, you are correct. It does fetch the entity, which is ugly. I still do not think this is significant for performance in most cases, and `Any()` is conceptually clearer, but it is true that it will fetch a full row instead of a scalar.

Comment: I have found it a performance issue. In my case the 'where' criteria are on an index, the index for performance reasons is not a covering index, so the db needs then to refer back to the table to retrieve the instance data.

Answer (score 3):

```
var exists = 1 == session.CreateQuery("select 1 from MyEntity where Property = :value")
    .SetValue("value", xxx)
    .UniqueResult<Int32?>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Ricardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239594/ricardo-peres) answer, this seems like the most efficient way to check if object exists using HQL. It doesn't COUNT and doesn't load the object unnecessarily:

```
var exists = session
    .CreateQuery("select 1 from Widget where _color = 'green'")
    .SetMaxResults(1)
    .UniqueResult<Int32?>()
    .HasValue;
```

It generates this SQL (note that this is SQLite, so LIMIT instead of TOP)

```
select
    1 as col_0_0_ 
from
    Widgets  
where
    Color='green' limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try:

```
public virtual T FindById<T>(int id)
{
    return session.Get(typeof(T), id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension method from the answers above. I choose to use the Any version but with a Select on the primary key the same amount of data will be returned depend on the primary key type.

```
public static bool Exists<TModel, TKey>(
    this IQueryable<TModel> query, Expression<Func<TModel, TKey>> selector, TKey id)
    where TKey : class
{
    return query
        .Select(selector)
        .Any(x => x == id);
}

public static Task<bool> ExistsAsync<TModel, TKey>(
    this IQueryable<TModel> query, Expression<Func<TModel, TKey>> selector, TKey id)
    where TKey : class
{
    return query
        .Select(selector)
        .AnyAsync(x => x == id);
}
```